# Windows Identity session management for silverlight / wpf

Tags: wpf, soap, authentication, wif

I'm testing WIF, most examples are in Asp.Net though and I'm more interested by WPF/Silverlight. 
How would you handle sessions in this case ? With Asp.net in case the soap service requests a new login, we are redirected to the login page, how can we do when using WPF or Silverlight ?

More generally speaking, how do you handle a refused connection ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the hands-on lab for Silverlight and WIF:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/IdentityTrainingCourse_SilverligthAndIdentity2010

As you'll see, the basic process is similar to a normal ASP.NET web application.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks. But how would it work for wpf ? (since opening a browser is not the most natural behaviour)

Comment: For WPF (or any type of Windows app), you'll need to use active federation, which doesn't redirect to a webpage but instead uses web services to perform authentication.  You can look at lab 4 here for an example: http://claimsid.codeplex.com/releases/view/68061.